# Metabase not connecting to MySQL (docker containers)

Tags: mysql, docker, metabase

I'm running metabase and MySQL in seperate docker containers, both connecting to the same bridge.

I can ping the MySQL container from the metabase container. However, when I try to connect to MySQL from the metabase interface, I am getting the following error:

```
"unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4 (socket was closed by server)".
```

Here is my config:

- Windows 10
- Metabase version v0.36.4 (196c1f6 release-0.36.x)
- 8.0.21 MySQL Community Server - GPL

And my docker network configuration:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "mysql-metabase-net",
        "Id": "bbe21c1873049a3ce0aee6f2e8b2cd3ba5c443cc655d685368f342b42e9d6e98",
        "Created": "2020-09-07T05:18:19.355990708Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "7c1dfaee4a8783aae6afccbbc1970d3fb971645a972c2484e67125b7aba027bc": {
                "Name": "my-container",
                "EndpointID": "7ee6b1f4b850f2a9389fa6cda311eb19e28016890eafd7659255d2fab9b7a38b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "cc261fe878298ec8199a700351195901a65f3575d395971a6f5268e9a0b9d93f": {
                "Name": "metabase",
                "EndpointID": "0c3541adc8d42c57a14c7d3f465111c2734718734432df5a61ee676628ef79b2",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Am I doing something wrong? Any idea what the issue could be?

Thanks for your help.

Jeremy

Comment: you're connecting using the hostname = container name or the private bridge ip?

Comment: Hi, I'm connecting on 172.19.0.1 and the port that the mysql container is on 3307. Anything else gave me a different error, I figured out this was the better way, but might be wrong. I tried to post the metabase log but was limited by the number of characters

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out I had my ports messed up. Further troubleshooting involving public key and SSL was solved [here](https://discourse.metabase.com/t/connection-to-mysql-fails/11498/9)